How to monitor users usage of GPG keys on company email server
I've been tasked to monitor our user's usage of PGP keys (ie: how many emails are sent/received using PGP). How can I go about doing this? We all use Ubuntu and the Thunderbird email client and Postfix/Dovecot.
I believe the standard mail.log generated by postfix doesn't contain information about email content and it is impossible to determine whether an email was encrypted by Thunderbird.
We have an internal Ubuntu keyserver but I'm not sure where the logs are for that. Or maybe I could look at when the key was last accessed on a user's laptop in ~/.gnupg? Or look for the gpg-agent process?

You will need to configure postfix to deliver all messages to a process that checks for GPG-encrypted payloads and then updates statistics somewhere. GPG doesn't regularly interact with a keyserver, so monitoring that will get you nothing. There's also no way to tell when a key was last accessed. Postfix has filtering facilities that may be useful for what you want to do.
